# How to create tableview without prototype cell

Tags: uitableview, swift

If I don't want to use a prototype cell in my tableview. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, do I still need to supply a cell identifier in code to dequeue a cell?

I have tried this but it throws a run time error when the tableview tries to populate:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It happens on this line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
```

I'm not sure what other line to use for dequeueing a cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to, or swift has no way to find out what kind of object you want to `dequeue`, therefore your got `nil` object.

You should use
 `- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

instead of 
`- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

It's because the first one actually returns `AnyObject` while `dequeue` without indexpath returns `AnyObject?`

In order to make your code works, either you change your code to `...forIndexPath`

or do this:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell?
if let cell = cell {
    //dequeue here
} else {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle,
reuseIdentifier reuseIdentifier: String?) ...
}
//config cell
return cell
```

In case you are kind of a do-all-things-in-code person, you need to register your `UITableViewCell` class to `tableView` like Mert suggests.

`tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: "Cell")`

---

Sample code:

```
// I remove all other things, just focus on what you need
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: "Cell")
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You can't use String?.  You need to supply a valid string there or it won't compile.  Can you post the dequeue code (you have just a comment there)?

Comment: I copied it from documentation, it does write `reuseIdentifer` as `String?`. That's weird. Well, check my sample code, it should works. This is for swift 1.2, if you use swift 1.1, change `as!` to `as`

Comment: Lots of errors: "Use of unresolved identifier 'forCellReuseIdentifier'" for registerClass.  Also "Use of unresolved identifier 'configureCell'".  Probably best if you tried the code first.  Kind of like slinging mud at the wall right now.

Comment: :D I said I removed all the other things :D Let's me explain: `configCell` is a `private func` that you set things up in your `cell`, like image, text for `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel`.

Comment: The "unresolved identifier" error should not be appeared because we registering and using the same `"Cell"` string for `reuseIdentifier` (as you can see in the code). I guess you have something in storyboard or with the code that you setting up your table ? no ? then you should post some sample code, I'll find it for you :)

Comment: I have it working now.  Your signature is not correct.  You should remove the word "identififer".

Comment: Your answer is good minus some minor issues.  Just to summerize, since I'm not using a prototype cell in IB, the only way to get the tableview to work is with registerClass()?   You don't need to assign the delegate/datasource in code.  It can be done in IB.  I was trying to see how far I could go with IB before I needed to use code when a prototype cell is not being used.

Comment: It's good when you figure things out. FYI, `prototype cell` and `static cell` are IB's things. There's no property/method of `UITableView` that set cell becomes `static` or `prototype`. They're just cell. Don't focus too much in that. And try to use only code, it's fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your table view register for that cell class

```
tableView.registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

, then you can try to dequeue a cell. if there is no cell to dequeue, you need to create a new one.

But your main problem here should be the following: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns an `optional`. if you want to return it as the cell, it would probably give error. you should make sure that you are returning a `non-optional` cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

Comment: When I try your register class code, I get an error that a "," is expected.

Comment: Also, the main issue isn't what you stated but instead, where do you get the identifier string (since this isn't present in IB).

Comment: "," is expected is not a real error, you just wrote something wrong, it is not about the functions you use.

Comment: The underscore in your code is causing the "," error.