# How to create tableview cells without using prototype cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my tableview, every cell will be different and determined by a JSON response from server. And there will be infinite possibilities. So defining a prototype for each type of cell is not possible.

For example, one cell will have labels and buttons, another cell have images and buttons in different orders.

How to achieve this dynamic structure in tableview cells?

Currently what I am doing is: adding views as subview in cellForRowAtIndexPath but scrolling is very laggy this way.

How to achieve this without affecting performance this much

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! MyCell

    for myview in data[indexPath.row].myviews{
        cell.addSubview(myview)
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: add this code in willDisplayCell for better performance.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS moving where it runs will not increase performance. It will just move the bottleneck somewhere else.

Comment: But I need to dequeue the cell in cellForRow right?

Comment: If every cell is going to be unique, there is really no need to dequeue with a single identifier. Each cell should have its own unique identifier.

Comment: @SwiftySwift - you need to do some testing to find out exactly where the "bottleneck" is... Assuming you are not trying to add an absurd number objects to a cell, you *could* create your cell with, say, 5 buttons, 5 image views, 5 labels, and then just show/hide as needed. That *might* be a little quicker than creating and adding elements. On the other hand, you may just want to re-think your UI... it's not always the best idea to try and present a really long scrolling view (particularly if "every row is unique")

Comment: @SwiftySwift similar question this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566531/how-to-create-tableview-without-prototype-cell

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a table view then your content is going to scroll vertically, right?

There is a physical limit to the amount of UI that you can put horizontally. Limited by the screen size.

So I'm guessing your UI parts are being laid out vertically in the cell?

So instead of laying out a button, label, image, another button, and a text field vertically in a cell...

Create a cell type called ButtonCell, LabelCell, ImageCell, MultiLineLabelCell, TextFieldCell, etc...

So now, instead of creating one cell with all these elements added. You instead create multiple cells each containing one type of UI. Now you can dequeue your cells in any particular order (driven by your JSON) and won't lose the performance.

Comment: So are you suggesting, each list item will now be section, and each input will be a cell?

Comment: @SwiftySwift yeah, if you still need to make sure you keep your individual data items separate then you could definitely make each `section` relate to an item. Rather then each `row` relate to an item. That way if something is tapped or changed on a particular cell you can still relate it back to the data by using `section` to get the item and `row` to get the relevant UI element in the data. etc...

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I see is to have empty cell and add/remove subviews as needed. But you should add new subviews to a cell only if you did not add them before.
For example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! MyCell

    if cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) == nil {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.tag = 1
        cell.contentView.addSubview(label)
    }

    let label = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1)
    // label config there

    return cell

}
```

Also don't forget to add subviews to cell's contentView not to cell itself.

Comment: Don't use `tag` in views... ever.

Comment: What problem with a tag?

Comment: This will only reduce the lag if user scrolls back up. The initial slow load I do not want will stay right?

Comment: Why there should be slow load? Lags can be if you synchronously load images from internet or using very big images.

Comment: Using tag in views encourages storing data in views. And then later retrieving data from those views. It is entirely the opposite of what should be done. They are the quick and dirty way to solve things when there are much more elegant solutions that tend to be quicker, easier and more maintainable than anything that uses tags.

Comment: Some further reading... http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-4-uiview.html

Comment: Images are loaded asynchronously however drawing inputs are lagging.

Comment: @Fogmeister I am not talking to store some data in a tag. But you are right about storing views in some variables. But I would prefer tags because it is more dynamic way to have different subviews bunched in some groups by tags.

Comment: @SwiftySwift You need find a way to reduce lags in drawing inputs. But it is another story :)